# Finding smallest dtype to safely cast an array to

Tags: numpy

Let's say I want to find the smallest data type I can safely cast this array to, to save it as efficiently as possible. (The expected output is `int8`.)

```
arr = np.array([-101,125,6], dtype=np.int64)
```

The most logical solution seems something like

```
np.min_scalar_type(arr) # dtype('int64')
```

but that function doesn't work as expected for arrays. It just returns their original data type.

The next thing I tried is this:

```
np.promote_types(np.min_scalar_type(arr.min()), np.min_scalar_type(arr.max())) # dtype('int16')
```

but that still doesn't output the smallest possible data type.

What's a good way to achieve this?

Comment: Applied to `arr` it returns the documented dtype: `For non-scalar
array ``a``, returns the vector's dtype unmodified.`

Comment: `np.can_cast('uint8','int8')` (from the `max`) is `False`.  `uint8` can have positive values that are too large for `int8`.  That explains why `promote_types` returns 'int16'.

Comment: @hpaulj Yea, I understood why my current solution doesn’t work but am looking for a good way that will work. For now I’ll probably implement something that manually checks if the min and max are within certain ranges, but there must be a more ‘best practice’ way.

Comment: @hpaulj I guess I meant that the function doesn’t work as *I* expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working solution I wrote. It will only work for integers.

```
def smallest_dtype(arr):
    arr_min = arr.min()
    arr_max = arr.max()
    for dtype_str in ["u1", "i1", "u2", "i2", "u4", "i4", "u8", "i8"]:
        if (arr_min >= np.iinfo(np.dtype(dtype_str)).min) and (arr_max <= np.iinfo(np.dtype(dtype_str)).max):
            return np.dtype(dtype_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is close to your initial idea:

```
np.result_type(np.min_scalar_type(arr.min()), arr.max())
```

It will take the signed int8 from arr.min() if arr.max() fits inside of it.